# How to return error message from service to controller and then to client

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, .net-core, error-handling

How can I return error message from service.cs to controller and then to client side (Angular) when element is null for example?
What is the correct way to return information what goes wrong on server side? I just want ot return ex.Message or string with information when for example element is null.

**Angular**

```
 getTree(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.baseURL + 'home/Tree/' + id)
      .pipe(
        retry(0),
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      );
  }




errorHandler(error) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Get client-side error
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      // Get server-side error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("Tree/{elementId}")]
 public FoodNode Tree(int elementId)
    {
        try
        {
            var json = _service.GetConnectionsForId(elementId);

            return json;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

**Service.cs**

```
  public ElementNode GetConnectionsForId(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            string message;

            Element element = _context.Elements.Find(id);
         }
         catch(Exception ex){
           return ex.Message;
         }
```

Comment: Why are you using exceptions to handle known failure cases?

Comment: ASP.NET Core? Maybe this can help : [Controller action return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: @Llama shoul I use onlu if(element !=null) or something like that?

Comment: Yes, that would be a better way to handle it. I dont' see why `GetConnectionsForId` doesn't simply return `null` if the element is `null`.

Comment: Oh ok thank you. I thought this is better way to say user what goes wrong on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw a `NoConnectionException` from your service:

```
public ElementNode GetConnectionsForId(int id)
{
    try
    {
        string message;
        Element element = _context.Elements.Find(id);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new NoConnectionException(ex);
    }
}

public class NoConnectionException : Exception
{
    public NoConnectionException(Exception inner) : base(inner)
    {
    }
}
```

Catch the `NoConnectionException` in your controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Tree/{elementId}")]
public ActionResult<FoodNode> Tree2(int elementId)
{
    try
    {
        var json = _service.GetConnectionsForId(elementId);
        return Ok(json);
    }
    // Beware: Give all the exceptions in your try-clause a unique name, otherwise they'll be null
    catch (NoConnectionException noConnEx)
    {
        return StatusCode(501); // Or whatever status code you want to assign to this
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

And handle the statuscode in your angular service:

```
getTree(id: number) {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.baseURL + 'home/Tree/' + id)
    .pipe(
      retry(0),
      catchError(this.errorHandler) // <-- I assume the error handler will pass you the status code so here you can look for 500 or 501 or ...
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I get error on client side but without message from service.

Comment: Passing internal error messages from the ASP.NET Core application/DbContext is usually not the best idea. Also you most likely want to translate the error message. This is usually done on the client side where you pick a translation depending on the httpStatusCode. However if you really want to, you can return a JsonResponse from the MVC controller.

Comment: Oh I see now that I forgot `return`. I changed it to `return StatusCode(500);`

Comment: Hmm so how can I tell the user that this item doesn't exist? Create a new client and server side method to check this?

Comment: `return NotFound();` from your controller method